# Sublime Text dynamic tmLanguage file

Tags: python, api, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext2

I have an issue on my github project that is meant to maintain a EJS syntax definition file for Sublime Text editor. (https://github.com/samholmes/EJS.tmLanguage/issues/1)

The issue is that users want to be able to customize what the opening and closing tags should be in EJS. I've set it to `<?` and `?>` respectively, because I prefer this personally. However, the "correct" or should I say the recommended default open and closing tags are `<%` and `%>` as you'll find on the EJS website.

So, what I'm wondering is if there is a way to customize this per installation of this package? I wouldn't know how this would work though. tmLanguage files are just XML files. So, my question is. On this line:

https://github.com/samholmes/EJS.tmLanguage/blob/master/EJS.tmLanguage#L579

Is there a way to make the regular expression generated by some setting file?

Any ideas on how I could solve this would be highly appreciated. I'm not familiar with Sublime's features or python API, so anyone with more information on this, please let me know what it is you think I should do.

Comment: Sublime Text 2 has a "Package Settings" system. If you want per-installation customization, you might want to look into how to correctly utilize that API in your plugin

Comment: Where could I go to "look into this". A link would be much appreciated.

Comment: A quick google search ("sublime text 2 plugin api") led me here: http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html; The other search results may also be of interest, as well as the many open-source plugins that can be analyzed and learned from

Comment: These APIs don't tell me how to edit a template file or something.

Comment: Have a look at some of the others in your Packages directory

Comment: Duplicate the file and make another one with your custom open tags, then you'll have two syntaxes which you can switch between through command palette.

Comment: @enrey How would I switch between them? AFAIK the tmLanguage file is loaded in automatically, so if I had two, I'd assume they both would be loaded in.

Comment: @Sam name it EJS-CustomTags.tmLanguage or something, it would be like different syntax

Comment: Thanks so much for the idea, I've successfully implemented this. :)

Comment: @enrey One thing missing is that my plugin doesn't remember the last tmLanguage file selected for EJS files. Instead, it uses the first tmLanguage that is for EJS file types. I need an event handler that gets called when a tmLanguage file is used; do you know of any such event in the Sublime Text API?

Comment: @sam I see you're asking on ##sublimetext too, look at  http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime_plugin.EventListener I guess you want on_load or something similar. In any case, you can set default syntax for each file, try google, it's everywhere.